# How do I enter 'y' automatically to apt-get?

Tags: shell, apt, apt-get

I'm trying to automate a server setup using a shell script.

I need to install a few dependencies with `apt-get` and some require the user to input `y` before the install continues.

My question is how do I make sure the shell script automatically inserts `y` every time it sees something like `Do you want to continue [Y/n]?` ?

I've tried `sudo apt-get install git << 'y'` and `'y' | sudo apt-get install git` but with no results.

What could I try next?

Comment: `apt-get install -y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `-y` or `--yes` flag as described in the `apt-get`man pages.

BTW there is even an option to `--force-yes`. So you got plenty of options at your hands.

Answer (score 1):

`yes | sudo apt-get install git`

`yes` writes the word 'yes' to standard output over and over and over again. It can also be used to do the same for other words (ie. `yes no | sudo apt-get...` to repeat 'no' to stdin).

Comment: pedantically, `yes` writes `y` to stdout. `yes yes` would write `yes`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `yes` command.

Like this:

```
yes | rm *.txt
```

This will remove any file, and the `yes` command means you don't have to answer the queries.

In your case,

```
yes | sudo apt-get install git
```

This is using the pipe functionaly to pipe "yes" responses into standard input.