# How to install pip non-interactively with apt?

Tags: apt

I am installing pip using the command `apt install python3-pip`. During the installation, `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]` question appears on the command line. I want the command to take `yes` as the default answer and continue. Is this possible? Or any other way of installing pip non-interactively? I tried `apt install --no-input python3-pip` did not work.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enter 'y' automatically to apt-get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704791/how-do-i-enter-y-automatically-to-apt-get)

Comment: @FlyingTeller, I have tried those solutions. I am getting this `: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?`

Comment: Then that is different problem than what you are originally asking. There are existing posts about it, like this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1109982/727997. As mentioned in [ask], please try to search first.